# Pop up window in visio

Tags: visio, visio2013

I am trying to to develop ESP jobs schedule chart sheet in Visio 2013. As there are lots of Jobs, I can't mentioned all the details of jobs in visio shape. So, i want  to show a pop up window which will appear when a crusor hiover over a specific shape, where i could see the predecessor, successor, average run time, output file and ect. could any one plese help me.

Comment: I'm going to suggest this in a comment, because it's not quite baked enough for an answer, but: you can use the Visio Application's MouseMove event to detect mouseover on a shape (using Page.SpatialSearch with the mouse coords), and then add a VBA UserForm showing the information you want to show.

Comment: Hi Jon Fournier : The problem is I want to show some text in different pop up window (as added by me) while hover the mouse over a particular shape. Could you suggest now.

Comment: I did suggest how.  The window would be a user form, and I told you how to detect mousing over a particular shape.